# VBA - Too Slow with With and selection Command. How Can I optimize it better to run faster?

Tags: vba, excel

I am selecting a range and using that selection inside the `With` Command and as you all know, the `.Selection` command is going to slow down the process. What is the better way to write this code, to run it faster?

Here goes my code:

```
Sheets(Currentsheetname).Range("A" & SelRowNumber + 1 & ":A" & lastrow).Select

With .Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
               xlBetween, Formula1:="Remove"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "Warning"
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = "Please select a value from the list available in the selected cell."
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is what it looks like with `Select` and `Selection` removed:

```
With Sheets(Currentsheetname).Range("A" & SelRowNumber + 1 & ":A" & lastrow).Validation

  .Delete
  .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                                            xlBetween, Formula1:="Remove"
                                            .IgnoreBlank = True
                                            .InCellDropdown = True
                                            .InputTitle = ""
                                            .ErrorTitle = "Warning"
                                            .InputMessage = ""
                                            .ErrorMessage = "Please select a value from the list available in the selected cell."
                                            .ShowInput = True
                                            .ShowError = True
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how to remove the selection and to speed up the process:

```
With Sheets(Currentsheetname).Range("A" & SelRowNumber + 1 & ":A" & lastrow).Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="Remove"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "Warning"
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = "Please select a value from the list available in the selected cell."
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Always try to avoid seletction and activation in VBA.

Comment: You are missing `with` at the beginning.